# CPP how to format strings to align to the right side

Tags: c++, formatting

I am looking for a simple CPP solution to align a string to the right size.

What do I mean by this?
here is an example:

the normal output would be

```
hello [message]
foo [message]
```

I would like it to output like this:

```
 hello [message]
   foo [message]
```

note: this is not for aligning a table but rather to know how to align a message by adding certain spaces to the left (or smth).

Comment: What do your text-books, tutorials or class-notes say about *I/O manipulators* like `std::setw` and `std::right`?

Comment: Try `std::format` if you're using msvc, or `fmt` library.

Comment: Like this https://godbolt.org/z/34Y6PWMh6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::setw(10) << "Hello" << " [message]" << std::endl ;
    std::cout << std::setw(10) << "foo" << " [message]" << std::endl ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just have a question, It looks like when I try to add ANSI colors, the formatting gets messed up. How could I fix this?

Comment: here is what my statement looks like: `std::cout << std::setw(10) << GREEN << topic << RESET << message << std::endl`

Comment: nvm, I fixed it.

Comment: Color in console applications is non-standard and depends on the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

In the  library, you can find std:right and std:setw which can help to justify O/P to the right.

If 'i' is your string, then below is a snippet that you can use :-

```
#include <iomanip>

cout << right
     << setw(20)
     << fixed
     << i << endl;
```

Comment: This works for me but how could I append a message to the end of "I"?

Comment: Yeah just do <<"Hello "<<"message"

Comment: I don't understand the right and fixed part tho, without them, It still worked